# Integer solutions for $a+b+c+d=0$, $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=24$

Tags: diophantine-equations

How to get all integer solutions for $$a+b+c+d=0,$$ and $$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=24$$

So far I've put $a=-b-c-d$ into 2nd equation and try to factorise it, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Trivial solution includes all permutations of $(3,-1,-1,-1) $.

Comment: @Rohan: Why do you refer to this as *trivial* (i.e., what makes it more trivial than any other solution)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $d=-a-b-c$,  you can  check the following identity:

$$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=-3(a+b)(a+c)(b+c).$$

Thus $$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)=-8,$$

and that easily gives you all integer solutions. For instance, the case

\begin{cases}
a+b=1 \\
a+c=1\\
b+c=-8 
\end{cases}

gives you $(a,b,c,d)=(5,-4,-4,3),$  and  the case

\begin{cases}
a+b=-2 \\
a+c=-2\\
b+c=-2 
\end{cases}

gives you $(a,b,c,d)=(-1,-1,-1,3).$